# how to close a softinputkeyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, onfocus, soft-input-panel

I have created a customauto EditText field. My problem with the text field is that when i click on the EditText the keyboard rises but when i click elsewhere the keyboard still remains open. Please help me in this issue

The name of the custom auto EditText is auto_list. I have attached the onFocusChangeListener

```
auto_list.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (hasFocus) {
                    getActivity()
                            .getWindow()
                            .setSoftInputMode(
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
                }
                else{
                    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
     InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
       .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputManager != null && activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
      inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
     .getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call this function because the else condition should be the one which calls this.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking hasFocus, this seems to be causing you problem. you should check something like this

```
    if(v.getId() == R.id.your_edit_text && hasFocus)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
try
    {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
     }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Ignore exceptions if any
            Log.e("KeyBoardUtil", e.toString(), e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in event on which you want to hide soft keyboard...

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(xxx.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

where `xxx` is the edit text in which you want to hide keyboard. do same if you have more than one edit texts on which you want to apply same functionality.